# 'View TensorBoard' goes to 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard, azure-databricks

​Hello,

I am trying to launch Tensor board on Tensorflow/Keras on Azure Databricks, 
but it will go to '502 Bad Gateway' after clicking 'View TensorBoard'.

Please advise how to fix this.

Thanks.

> ```
> Lo​oking for active tensorboard process...  
> Active tensorboard processkilled... 
> Starting tensorboard process...  
> Tensorboard process started.
> TensorBoard log directory set to: /dbfs/ml/lenet/train/1570698969.0092866. View TensorBoard
> ```

Comment: Could you please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-monitor-tensorboard), hope this helps.Thanks

Comment: Here's a [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/troubleshooter-bad-gateway-502-errors-in-azure-application-gateway-15736e04-810c-24ca-53e3-0b95e653c168) for trouble shooting the 502 bad gateway error in Azure.